# partial derivatives in three variables for implicitly defined function

Tags: calculus

> Assume that $F(x,y,z)=0$ defines $z$ implicitly as a function of $x$ and
>   $y$. Show that

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = - \frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial x}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}}$

> and

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = - \frac{\frac{\partial F}{\partial y}}{\frac{\partial F}{\partial z}}$

> now for

$F(x,y,z(x,y))=0$

$\frac{d}{dx}F(x,y,z(y,x)) = \frac{\partial 0}{\partial x}$

$F_x\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} + F_z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=0$

$F_x+F_z\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}=0$

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}= - \frac{F_x}{F_z}$

> and similarly for $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$
>   so far so good - but how do I use these formulas to find $\frac{\partial z}{\partial x}$
>   and $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ for

$x^2-3yz^2+xyz-2=0$

> can I say

$-\frac{F_x}{F_z}= -\frac{2x+yz}{xy-6yz}$

> and

$-\frac{F_y}{F_z}= -\frac{xy-3z^2}{xy-6yz}$